# How to append a one-page-pdf to a Huge PDF file

Tags: pdf, merge, insert, append

I have a huge pdf file（which is 1TB or more）and a small pdf which only have one page, is there any way to append the small pdf to the end of huge one at a acceptable cost of time, without rewriting them to the disk?

I have tried mupdf/podofo but get nothing.

thanks.

Comment: You would want to do what is called an Incremental update, which allows editing a PDF file, but all the changes are just appended to the end of the original PDF. So the original 1TB PDF data on disk would not be touched. You would just be appending bytes to the end of the file. You need to find a SDK/library that supports saving changes as Incremental.